# How does Delta Lake (deltalake) guarantee ACID transactions?

Tags: databricks, acid, delta-lake

What mechanisms does Delta Lake use to ensure the atomicity, consistency, isolation, and durability of transactions initiated by user operations on a DeltaTable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 0. the DeltaLog

**Deltalog** = *Delta Lake*'s transaction log.

The deltalog is a collection of ordered json files. It acts as a single source of truth giving to users access to the last version of a `DeltaTable`'s state.

#### 1. Atomicity

- *Delta Lake* breaks down every operation performed by an user into *commits*, themselves composed of *actions*.
- A commit is recorded in the deltalog only once each of its actions has successfully completed (else it is reverted and restarted or an error is thrown), ensuring its **atomicity**.

#### 2. Consistency

The **consistency** of a `DeltaTable` is guaranteed by their strong schema checking.

#### 3. Isolation

Concurrency of commits is managed to ensure their **isolation**. An optimistic concurrency control is applied:

- When a commit execution starts, the thread snapshots the current deltalog.
- When the commit actions have completed, the thread checks if the *Deltalog* has been updated by another one in the meantime:

  - If not it records the commit in the deltalog
  - Else it updates its `DeltaTable` view and attempts again to register the commit, after a step of reprocessing if needed.

#### 4. Durability

Commits containing actions that mutate the `DeltaTable`'s data need to finish their writes/deletions on underlying *Parquet* files (stored on the filesystem) to be considered as successfully completed, making them **durable**.

---

Further readings:

[*Diving Into Delta Lake: Unpacking The Transaction Log*](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/08/21/diving-into-delta-lake-unpacking-the-transaction-log.html)

[ACID properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)